# Are "serving url" valid after migration to datastore HRD?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am migrating my application from master/slave to HRD and I realized one thing: if I complete the migration (so that the old GAE master/slave project points to the new one) all the old serving url remain valid?

In fact when a user in my web-app upload an image I store this path:

> servingUrl =
>   ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService().getServingUrl(blobKey);

This is very important to me because I use the serving url also externally from the app!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old serving URLs will remain valid as long as your old app remains active, with the blobs they reference in the datastore. If you delete the app or the blobs, the serving URLs may go away at any time.

Comment: Not so if they have migrated their blobs - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/migration

Comment: @StuartLangley No, unfortunately, since the blob key changes in the migration, so does the serving URL.

Comment: The URL generated has nothing to do with the BlobKey ... Too bad I can't chat about it with you in the office anymore ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this should still work fine.